# books related to designing a good iphone application architecture

Tags: iphone, ipad, architecture

I am few months old to iphone / ipad development. I know few coding standards, few coding practices. I am not aware of design principles and stuff for building a good iphone application architecture. Guide me with link / books which can help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought 'Cocoa Design Patterns' by Erik M. Buck was really great.

[http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Design-Patterns-Erik-Buck/dp/0321535022](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to give a look at this two web-resources:

[Core Application Architecture for iPhone](http://www.technolike.com/archives/86/core-application-architecture-for-iphone.html) (describe life cycle and event cycles of an iPhone application and also provide a summary of some of the key design patterns used throughout the development of iPhone applications.)

[An Overview of the iPhone Architecture](http://thecoffeedesk.com/news/index.php/2009/05/17/iphone-architecture/) (A detailed overview of the iPhone’s functionality)